# Nested Classes sharing data

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a winform program and a Dll that stores nested classes. One of these is a Permissions class, that basically acts as a permissions director for what can be used by whom in either the winform or the Dll.

The winform needs an instance of the Permission class, so it can direct flow of code. The Dll also needs this too.

The Dll structure simplified looks like this

```
Master Class
     Permission Class (creates the permissions)
     Worker Class (needs to know permissions)
     Other Class (needs to know permissions)
End Master class
```

MY idea was that I would create an instance of Permission class in winform and then ‘duplicate’ it in the Dll. This way I would not have to pass the reference of the Permission class instance from the winform back to the DLL, worker class (and others). And they would be in synch if winform instance were to update.

I thought I would do this by creating a Public Shared new Permission class instance in the Master Class, but that does not work, the instance is created but does not update. Im obviously wrong here.

Is there an acceptable way of creating something like the above scenario?

EDIT --------------

Im very new to the OOP concept. The permission class uses one external variable, that is the licence key, the permission class then splits the licence into various variables, each representing a different permission for different things. So, when I create the instance of the Permission class in the Form Exe like:

Perms as new Masterclass.Permission(LicenceKey)

it creates the one instance I want to use, in the Exe, but this instance is not available in the DLL.

Based on Olivier’s suggestion, how do I structure the code to have one instance of Perms being shared in the Exe and other classes within the Masterclass? I would do it in spaghetti code as a global variable in the project and its done, but now I have OOP and DLL’s and I can’t get my (old) head around it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to have one single `Permission` object throughout the whole lifetime of the application shared by all assemblies, create singleton objects to share data. You can do so by declaring a `Public Shared ReadOnly` field (or property) and making the constructor `Private`, so nobody else can create another instance. This ensures that only one single object exists.

```vb
Public Class Master
    Public Class Permission
        Public Shared ReadOnly Instance As Permission = New Permission()

        Private Sub New()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Then you can access the permissions with

```vb
Dim p = Master.Permission.Instance
```

or

```vb
Master.Permission.Instance.SomeMember
```

Note that the nested class `Permission` is nested statically as declaration. The outer class acts as namespace or scope. You do not need to create an instance of the surrounding class to access the inner class. Instances of nested classes are not nested in instances of the surrounding class. I.e., instances of `Master` and instances of `Permission` exist as separate, non-nested objects.

On the other hand, if you want one `Permission` object (an object being an instance of a class) per `Master` object, you must have a `Permission` property in the `Master` class. It makes no difference whether the class declarations themselves are nested or not. Usually, you would declare them as non nested in separate vb files.

```vb
Public Class Master
    Public ReadOnly Property Permissions As New Permission()
End Class

Public Class Permission
End Class
```

---

**Don't duplicate any code!** This code must be in one assembly only. Typically you would place it in a VB Class Library Project (this creates a DLL) and reference this project in other projects where you need the permissions.

The organisation of the assemblies is completely independent from the question of the lifetime of the objects, nesting etc.

The organisation of the assemblies only affects the availability of the declarations, not the availability of the objects and sharing of data, because all the data exists in one single memory scope at runtime.

---

This works only within one single Process. When you start an executable, it loads the EXE and the referenced DLL's into the same memory space. The EXE and the DLL's can therefore share objects.

However, if you start different Processes (i.e., EXE's in Windows), each of them will get its own memory space. The processes do not share their memory with other processes!

If you want to share live data between processes you must use [Interprocess Communication](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET/Interprocess_Communication)

Seee also: [Partitioning Your Code Base Through .NET Assemblies and Visual Studio Projects](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/partitioning-your-code-base-through-net-assemblies-and-visual-studio-projects/)

Comment: Thank you for the added explanation. Im very new to OOP. What you are saying makes sense and in a nutshell is what I need. Unfortunately I cant wrap my head around it just yet. I added more to my question.